# Child cannot trigger function that belongs to the parent in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, parent, children

I have a **modal parent component** and a **form child component**. The function that opens and closes the modal is in the parent, but the submit function is in the child. What I want to do is to close the modal on submit, but for that I need the **submit function from the child** to trigger the **close modal function from the parent**. I know how to pass a function from `< Parent />` to `< Child />`, but in here the difference is that the child is returned in the parent in this form `{children}`. How can I do this when the child is returned in this form ?

This is the modal component or the parent:

```
<ModalInMobile
      id="SearchFiltersMobile.filters"
      isModalOpenOnMobile={this.state.isFiltersOpenOnMobile}
      onClose={this.cancelFilters}
      showAsModalMaxWidth={showAsModalMaxWidth}
      onManageDisableScrolling={onManageDisableScrolling}
      containerClassName={modalContainerStyles}
      closeButtonMessage={modalCloseButtonMessage}
    >
      <button className={showListingsButtonStyles} onClick={this.closeFilters}>
      X
        </button>
      {this.state.isFiltersOpenOnMobile ? (
        <div className={modalFilterWrapperStyles}>{children[this.state.renderingModals]}</div>
      ) : null} 
    </ModalInMobile>
```

Comment: have a look at https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/passing-data-props-children/

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloneElement to pass your props to your children.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent>
          <Child />
      </Parent>
    </div>
  );
}



const Child = ({ parentProps }) => {


  return (<div>I am a child ({parentProps})</div>)

}

const Parent = ({ children }) => {

  const iAmProps = "i am a prop"

  const childProps = React.Children.map(children, child => {

    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { parentProps: iAmProps }); //add your props here.
    }
    return child;
  });

  return ( <>{childProps}</>)

}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-lamarr-mwcvi?file=/src/App.js:0-661)

Comment: The thing is that I cannot do your second step in the parent because the child is not in a component form like <Child /> , is just {children}

Comment: it's not in your question codes. Why don't you show the codes that need to be debug? If you don't show the proper codes that need to be debug, you wasted everybody's time, in this case, mine.

Comment: he did - "but in here the difference is that the child is returned in the parent in this form {children}"

Comment: added answer update to pass props to props.children